# Firebase Admin SDK Auth error "TOO_MANY_ATTEMPTS_TRY_LATER"

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm using firebase admin sdk in my cloud functions and I'm getting error randomly in some executions when trying to get a user by uid .

`let userRecord = await admin.auth().getUser(userId);`

The error details are:

```
{"error":{"code":400,"message":"TOO_MANY_ATTEMPTS_TRY_LATER",
 "errors":[{ "message":"TOO_MANY_ATTEMPTS_TRY_LATER",
             "domain":"global","reason":"invalid"}]
 }
}
```

My cloud function executes on a real time database `write` and can be triggered for multiple users. In total I have 4 auth function calls in one execution first is the above one, second call is to again get user by `uid` or `email`, third call is `generateEmailVerificationLink` and the last call is `generatePasswordResetLink`.

I have checked the rate limits in documentation for auth but there is no mention of rate limit for these operation. Also the error `TOO_MANY_ATTEMPTS_TRY_LATER` was only mentioned in REST API for sign up with email password.

If this error is due to rate limit what should I change to prevent this error given these 4 calls are necessary for the operation needed on database write?.

EDIT:

I have identified the actual call which is throwing too many attempts error. The calls `auth().generateEmailVerificationLink()` and `auth().generatePasswordResetLink()` throw this error when called too many times.

I called these two in loop with 100 iterations and waited for the promises. The first executions finishes without any errors i.e. 200 requests. But starting second execution as soon as the first one ends will throw the error of too many attempts. So I think these two calls have limit. Now I'm trying to reduce these calls and reuse the link information. Other calls like `getUserByEmail` works fine.

```
let promises = [];
let auth = admin.auth();
let hrstart = process.hrtime()
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    promises.push(auth.getUserByEmail("user email"));
    promises.push(auth.generateEmailVerificationLink("user email", {url: `https://app.firebaseapp.com/path`}));
    promises.push(auth.generatePasswordResetLink("user email", {url: `https://app.firebaseapp.com/path`}));

}

Promise.all(promises)
    .then(value => {
        let hrend = process.hrtime(hrstart);
        console.log(hrend);
        // console.log(value)
    });
```

Comment: You mention there are four calls.  Please show the entire batch of code.

Comment: Hey Umar, can you provide information on which API call is throwing the error? Is it on the 4th call to `generatePasswordResetLink`?

Comment: I'm currently investigating this issue more, there are calls to auth operations in 2 different firebase functions executions, so I will get more information. Regarding the error it's on the first getUser call. I think one execution gets to 3rd or 4th call and second execution then fails on getUser call, maybe because execution is in parallel.

Comment: I'll get back with more information and code where necessary.

Comment: Also you need to optimize your calls. Why do you need to lookup the user by uid and then by email? As for email verification vs password reset, why do you need to call both on the same user? I believe the password reset link should also verify the user.

Comment: Yes I'm optimizing my calls after this error, by reusing information where possible. I either get user by id or email, based on what is available. Password reset link is optional in my case so I cannot use it always.

Comment: @DougStevenson please see the edited question. Thanks.

Comment: @bojeil please see the edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was specifically in the operation `auth.createEmailLink`. This function has following limit: **20QPS/I.P address** where QPS is (**query per second**). This limit can be increased by submitting the use case to Firebase.

I got this information from firebase support after submitting my issue.

Link to my github issue: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/458

Answer (score 1):

I was way under 20QPS but was receiving this exception. In fact, it would always throw the `TOO_MANY_ATTEMPTS_TRY_LATER` exception on the 2nd attempt.

It turned out to be usage of `FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance` instead of instantiating a static instance thusly:

In class definition:
`private readonly FirebaseApp _firebase;`

In class constructor:
`_firebase = FirebaseAdmin.FirebaseApp.Create();`

In function:

```
var auth = FirebaseAuth.GetAuth(_firebase);
var actionCodeSettings = new ActionCodeSettings()
{
    ...
};
var link = await auth.GenerateEmailVerificationLinkAsync(email, actionCodeSettings);
return link;
```

Comment: Im not sure if I follow, can you eloaborate with what is the actual problem and solution here? I have the same issue, and cant quite wrap my head around this

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54782967/5515861, I want to add another solution if you found this issue while trying to create custom email verification.

Inspired by the response in this GitHub isssue https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/458#issuecomment-933161448 .

> I am also seeing this issue. I have not ran admin.auth().generateEmailVerificationLink in over 24hrs (from anywhere else or any user at all) and called it just now only one time (while deployed in the prod functions environment) and got this 400 TOO_MANY_ATTEMPTS_TRY_LATER error ...
> But, the client did also call the Firebase.auth.currentUser.sendEmailVerification() method around same time (obviously different IP).
> Could that be the issue?

My solution to this issue is by adding a retry. e.g.

```js
exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.runWith({failurePolicy: true}).auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
    functions.logger.log("Running email...");
    const email = user.email;
    const displayName = user.displayName;
    const link = await auth.generateEmailVerificationLink(email, {
      url: 'https://mpj.io',
    });

    await sendWelcomeEmail(email, displayName, link);
});
```

The `.runWith({failurePolicy: true})` is key.

It s giving you an error because your cloud functions/backend call the `generateEmailVerificationLink` while at the same time the default behaviour of the Firebase is also doing the same and it is counted as 20QPS. It some weird Google Rate Limit accounting rule. So my solution is just to add a retry.

The Downside is, it is calling twice, so if the call is billable, it might be billable twice.