# Firebase verifyPassword returning TOO_MANY_ATTEMPTS_TRY_LATER

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Using Firebase for authentication, I am seeing behavior that seems like extremely aggressive progressive lockout (after 1 or 2 failed attempts, having to wait 15 to 30 seconds to retry), yet I cannot find any documentation of such behavior or whether it is possible to modify it.

The specific behavior I am seeing is that if I submit a valid username but invalid password (using `Firebase.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword()`), I will get `auth/user-not-found` results anywhere from 1 to 5 times, then I will start to receive `auth/too-many-requests`/`TOO_MANY_ATTEMPTS_TRY_LATER`

Once I receive this result, I can submit the valid password for the same account and will continue receiving the `TOO_MANY_ATTEMPTS_TRY_LATER` result until I wait a yet-undetermined amount of time (sometimes 15 seconds, other times up to a minute)

If instead, once I receive the `TOO_MANY_ATTEMPTS_TRY_LATER` result, I immediately submit a signInWithEmailAndPassword request for another account, they fail or succeed on their own accord - suggesting that the "lockout" is based on the account not my source IP or client.

Is this known and expected behavior? If so, is there anywhere to modify the aggressiveness of the lockout trigger? My users are getting confused because they are seemingly not being allowed into the app when they are certain they have gotten the correct password - many times after only a single failed password attempt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase Admin SDK Auth error "TOO\_MANY\_ATTEMPTS\_TRY\_LATER"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54703649/firebase-admin-sdk-auth-error-too-many-attempts-try-later)

Comment: @Kundan, sadly it doesn't. Their issue turned out to be triggering the 20 QPS limit... which I am getting nowhere near. I can trigger this behavior with normal user interaction, far less than 1 query per second

Comment: This could be helpful too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157963/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-login-attempts-in-firebase